# Mostrar lo que se seleccione de un <select>

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo mostrar datos en un `<input>` de JavaScript, de acuerdo a lo que se seleccione de un `<select>`?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function mostrarprecio() {
    if (document.getElementById('pizza').value = "0")
    {
        document.getElementById('precio').value = "0";
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('pizza').value == "1") {
        precio = "15000";
    }

}
</script>

<form>
    Seleccione la pizza:
    <select id="pizza" onchange="mostrarprecio()">
        <option value="0" id="0" ></option>
        <option value="15000" id="1">Queso</option>
        <option value="18000" id="2">Jamon</option>
        <option value="22000" id="3">Jamon y Queso</option>
        <option value="30000" id="4">Especial</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="precio" />
```

Comment: Tienes un error en la condición del `if`: estás asignando en lugar de comparar, por lo que siempre se irá por la misma rama del `if`. Aparte de eso, parece que confundes el concepto de valor (`value`) e identificador (`id`) y por eso "falla" tu función JS.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1085801/1983854

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que deseas mostrar en el input 'precio' es el precio, puedes hacer esto:

```js
function mostrarprecio() {
  var pizza = document.getElementById("pizza"),
     precio = document.getElementById("precio");

  precio.value = pizza.value;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Seleccione la pizza:
  <select id="pizza" onchange="mostrarprecio()">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="15000">Queso</option>
    <option value="18000">Jamon</option>
    <option value="22000">Jamon y Queso</option>
    <option value="30000">Especial</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="precio" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sólo necesitas modificar tu función con lo siguiente.

```
function mostrarprecio() {
    var pizzaSelect = document.getElementById("pizza");
    var optionSelected = pizzaSelect.options[pizzaSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("precio").value = optionSelected;
}
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Te puedo ayudar con jQuery, ya que me simplifica la cantidad de código.

```
$('select#pizza').change(function(){
  $('input').val($(this).val());  
});
```

Y al select, ya puedes quitarle el onchange.

Un saludo,
Christian

Comment: Ojo! Tu código asigna a **todos los inputs** el valor de del _select#pizza_